# Common Questions side bar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, duplicate-suggestions

Not *100%* sure how to use this site but I think this is the right place to put this so I shall give it ago. I had a little look around and couldn't find anything close to what I am suggesting here.

### The Idea!

I spend a lot of my time on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in the CSS section. A lot of the time I see the same questions keep popping up. This is mainly due to new users being lazy and not searching or just looking at the titles without going in to look at the content.

So what if when you search something on one of the sides of the website you get a sidebar with the title of "Most Common Questions". This should also be on the side from the moment you get onto the website. That way you can have look through what the most comment question is on the whole site, and as you make your way through the site (clicking tags, etc.) it will filter.

Now I'm not *100%* sure how we would get the common question as it could be a number of ways or a mixture of all.

**Examples:**

- Get the highest reported duplicates using the same tags
- Keywords within the title
- New voting system for "most common questions"

These are just a few of the top of my head. So using this we could start limiting the amount of duplicate questions. At the moment there is "Similar Questions" & "Questions that may already have your answer". This is close to what I'm talking about but this only seems to use keywords. I would like a more refined sidebar that can pick up on most common questions.

An example of a question I see almost every day is "Sticky Footer". New users are not sure what the name is for a footer that sits at the bottom of there page is so they just type "Footer that stays at bottom of page". If we could link these sorts of titles/keywords/tags together and form a list I feel this could cut down the amount of duplicate questions we will get and give new users an easier time warming up to the site.

I hope a lot of this has made sense, I could keep going on about possible ways to tell users there questions have already been answers but that will do for now.

Comment: This is more or less what the "Questions that may already have your answer" section when asking a question already does. Its not perfect but this is its aim

Comment: @RichardTingle I just made a little update to my post as I didn't make it all to clear. Im more suggestion that this is on the side of the site from the moment you go onto it. My updated part - `This should also be on the side from the moment you get onto the website. That way you can have look through what the most comment question is on the whole site, and as you make your way through the site(clicking tags etc) it will filter.` This will give people and chance to see what are the common questions and hopefully filter down the amount of duplicates.

Comment: O I see, the [frequent tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent) is like that. I think it sorts by how many times a question has been closed as a duplicate of it; it can be for all questions or for a tag. It's not wildly visible at present however

Comment: @RichardTingle I have never really understood the "frequent tab", the questions seem to be random and some of them are not even that common (from what I see). I also feel not many people will use it, I have never used it. With a sidebar I feel it would be a lot smarter/ easier to show users common question.